# TypeError: Cannot read property 'location' of undefined (jest)

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, react-router, jestjs, enzyme

I have a simple component that uses useLocation hook from React Router.

// App.jsx

```js
import React from 'react';
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  const location = useLocation();
  const pathName = location.pathname;
  useEffect(() => {
    // Use pathName here
  }, [pathName]);
}
```

// App.test.js

```js
import App from './App';

describe('App component', () => {
  it('Renders correctly', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<App />);

    expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

// Update App.test.js (with jest mock)

```js
import App from './App';

describe('App component', () => {
  jest.mock('react-router-dom', () => ({
    useLocation: jest.fn().mockReturnValue({
      pathname: '/another-route',
      search: '',
      hash: '',
      state: null,
      key: '5nvxpbdafa',
    }),
  }));

  it('Renders correctly', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<App />);

    expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

Could you please tell me how I can fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to move the call to `jest.mock` outside of describe?

Comment: Hi @JohnnyZabala. Thanks for your help. Yes, I tried that too, but didn't work.

Answer (score 24):

Just move your `jest.mock` declaration to the top of the file and it should work:

```
import App from './App';

jest.mock('react-router-dom', () => ({
    useLocation: jest.fn().mockReturnValue({
      pathname: '/another-route',
      search: '',
      hash: '',
      state: null,
      key: '5nvxpbdafa',
    }),
}));

describe('App component', () => {
  it('Renders correctly', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<App />);

    expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

Comment: Hi @mgarcia, I appreciate your help. There were 2 issues with the code, and the first one was, trying to mock inside `describe`. Thanks a lot for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: I get TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'hash' of '(0 , _reactRouterDom.useLocation)(...)' as it is undefined. when using const { hash, search } = useLocation(); in my component. Any ideas?

Answer (score 8):

In case, anybody else faces a similar problem.

There were 2 issues with my approach. First, I used mock inside describe (thanks Johnny and MGarcia to help me figure that out).

However, I got another error after I moved mock code. Error: `React.createElement: type is invalid — expected a string`

That was my another Jest newbie mistake, and forgot that it's all JavaScript under the hood. With this approach, the side effect of mocking useLocation is rest of the methods from `react-router-dom` are made unavailable.

This is the approach that worked for me:

https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/936#issuecomment-265074320

Final solution:

```js
function mockFunction() {
  const original = require.requireActual('react-router-dom');
  return {
    ...original,
    useLocation: jest.fn().mockReturnValue({
      pathname: '/another-route',
      search: '',
      hash: '',
      state: null,
      key: '5nvxpbdafa',
    }),
  };
}

jest.mock('react-router-dom', () => mockFunction());
```

Comment: mock can't be in describe (or test)?     what if I need to change the mocked value (pathname) from test to test (or from describe to describe)?

Comment: requireActual is not a function .. perhaps you had a different version

Comment: use jest.requireActual instead of require.requireActual

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that you need to specify that you are using es6 module syntax. Try this:

```js
import App from './App';



jest.mock('react-router-dom', () => ({
    __esModule: true,
    useLocation: jest.fn().mockReturnValue({
      pathname: '/another-route',
      search: '',
      hash: '',
      state: null,
      key: '5nvxpbdafa',
    }),
  }));

describe('App component', () => {
  it('Renders correctly', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<App />);

    expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

[Reference.](https://remarkablemark.org/blog/2018/06/28/jest-mock-default-named-export/)

Comment: Hi @Johnny, I appreciate your help. There were 2 issues with the code, and the first one was, trying to mock inside `describe`. Thanks a lot for pointing me in the right direction.